# Should I be using script tags in ejs files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm learning how to develop a node application. It's an app where people can post events happening around the city.

I have an ejs file, new.ejs, that allows users to submit a new event. Obviously there is an event start time and end time. I want to make sure that the end time is AFTER the start time, so I simply added a script to do that, as follows:

```
          <!-- EVENT DATE AND TIME -->
          <div class=row>
              <!-- DATE -->
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="date">Date *</label>
                  <input name="date" type="date" class="form-control" id="date"> 
              </div>
              <!--START TIME -->
              <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                  <label for="starttime">Start Time *</label>
                  <input name="starttime" type="text" class="form-control" id="starttime">
              </div>
              <!--END TIME -->
              <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                  <label for="endtime">End Time *</label>
                  <input name="endtime" type="text" class="form-control" id="endtime">
              </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#starttime').timepicker();
                    $('#endtime').timepicker({
                        'minTime': '12:00am',
                        'showDuration': true
                    });
                    $('#starttime').on('changeTime', function() {
                        $('#endtime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', $(this).val());
                    });
              </script>
          </div> <!-- END OF ROW -->
```

Now this works just fine, it does what I want it to do.

However, I know that EJS is designed to take back-end (node) javascript code and render it out into the view.

My question is:

1. Is adding front-end code between  tags a hack? I.e, is this proper coding practice? If not, what is a better way of doing this?
2. Right now, I just have a small amount of code between my script tags. As I continue to develop the application, what happens if the code gets way too long? Should it remain in the ejs file? Seems too messy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your app is server-side rendered (not a Single Page Application), then your approach is sound.
2. You can put the your code in JS files in a `/public` folder and configured your node server to serve those files as static files, and add `<script>` tags in the `.ejs` files that reference those JS files.

I have a sample project with such an implementation. [This](https://github.com/yangshun/nutty-ninjas/blob/master/views/arena.jade) will be your ejs file (jade for my case) and [this](https://github.com/yangshun/nutty-ninjas/tree/master/public/js) is where you put your script files. Lastly, configure your app to serve static assets from a directory like [this](https://github.com/yangshun/nutty-ninjas/blob/master/app.js#L23).