# What is the replacement for Document in js when using ejs format

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am using ejs to do my html stuff, and can't use the regular document.getElementById('id') stuff in here.

It says document not defined.

So I am wondering what is the replacement for it??

This is the code:

```
<% var formToAttach = document.getElementById('formToAttach'); %>

<% var selectElement = document.createElement('select'); %>
<% selectElement.id = "states"; %>
<% selectElement.setAttribute('name','search'); %>

<% var option = document.createElement('option'); %>
<% option.setAttribute('value', placeName["loc"]); %>

<% selectElement.appendChild(option); %>

<% formToAttach.appendChild(selectElement); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put them in a normal `<script>` tag instead of the ejs one.

Please have a look at another post regarding a similar issue:

[Should I be using script tags in ejs files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176097/should-i-be-using-script-tags-in-ejs-files)